# How to word wrap in sublime text's console?

Tags: sublimetext2

I mean sublime text 2.I wanna achieve something like line 4. Just make console show the same.

[image: example]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turn (View -> Word Wrap) ON and restart the application. If its already on then turn it off and do the same.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I've achieved line 4. I wonder how to achieve the same in the console.

Comment: @Yearner These instructions **do** work for the console.  Just open the console first (ctrl-`) then follow the instructions above.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the Key Binding for word wrap toggling.
Go to Preferences -> Key Bindings, add the togging command to whatever key combination you want:

```
[
    //...
    { "keys": ["alt+z"], "command": "toggle_setting", "args": {"setting": "word_wrap"}}
]
```